# Receive all multicast ICMPv6 packets on Linux

Tags: linux, network-programming, ipv6, multicast

I would like to receive *all* multicast IPv6 packets arriving on a certain interface, without resorting to operate on layer 2, if that is possible.

I open a socket for raw ICMPv6 packets, and receiving unicast packets dedicated for my machine works just fine. However many ICMPv6 packets are link-local multicast (e.g. neighbor solicitations). What's the right way to listen for all multicast traffic, including solicited-node multicast? Currently I try to add a multicast group with IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, but this does not seem to work. Here's my code:

```
/* open RAW socket to receive on */
if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6)) < 0) {
    perror("socket");
}

/* get device index */
memset(&if_idx, 0, sizeof(struct ifreq));
strncpy(if_idx.ifr_name, DEVNAME, IFNAMSIZ-1);
if (ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &if_idx) < 0) {
    perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
}

/* configure to receive all multicast packets on this interface */
memset(&mreq, 0, sizeof(struct ipv6_mreq));
inet_pton(AF_INET6, "ff02::", &mreq.ipv6mr_multiaddr);
mreq.ipv6mr_interface = if_idx.ifr_ifindex;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, IPV6_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq,
            sizeof(struct ipv6_mreq)) < 0) {
    perror("setsockopt");
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What I want must be possible somehow. I tried ff02:: and ff02::1:ff00:0 as groups, and the latter even made setsockopt fail. What's going on? Unfortunately there's very little documentation on IPv6 multicast programming.

Comment: Yes, and this is part of the multicast address I am specifying.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are talking about. Scope IDs are not relevant here; they matter for *sending* packets, not for *receiving* them. What matters here is only the interface, and that is correctly set.

Comment: UDP?! I want to receive ICMPv6 packets. That's not UDP at all! I have to use raw sockets to work with ICMPv6. Why does IPv6 multicast not work with raw sockets? Where is this documented? My sources on the contrary say it only works with DGRAM and RAW sockets. BTW: if you wonder about the out-of-context comments above, I replied to a someone that now decided to delete his or her comments. Sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be impossible after all. I am now using Linux's AF_PACKET socket type with "cooked" mode (SOCKET_DGRAM) to access the raw IPv6 packets with link-layer header and a BPF to filter out ICMPv6 ND packets - at least I won't need to deal with parsing the ethernet header this way, and I can possibly support other link-layer types more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SOL_IPV6` instead of `SOL_SOCKET`.

Test subscribing to `ff80::1` and generating traffic with `ping6 -I eth0 ff08::1`.

Comment: This works for specific multicast groups, but I need to receive traffic from *all* solicited-node multicast groups. These are 2^24 groups, and it's definitely not practical to add them all (I even tried that, just because).

Comment: @dietr that's how multicast works: an IGMP subscription is required for network infrastructure to forward you the traffic.  For local-link traffic you can try using `PF_PACKET` but you still might need some switch reconfiguration or basically use a hub.

Comment: Well, I am only interested in the *multicast traffic that actually arrives on the machine* (and generally that is at least all link-local multicast). I actually wrote that in the initial post. IGMP (or the IPv6 equivalent) is not involved at all.